# Decryption with RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(byte[], bool) issue

Tags: c#, encryption, byte, rsa

I've got this issue when trying to decrypt an RSA-encrypted byte array, using a specified private key: basically, after calling the .Decrypt() method, all I get back is an empty byte array (byte[0]).

Here's the code:

```
static RSACryptoServiceProvider eng;
    static RSACryptoServiceProvider gne;

    static RSA()
    {
        eng = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        gne = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        eng.FromXmlString(xmlKKEY);
        gne.FromXmlString(xmlPKEY);
        eng.ImportParameters(eng.ExportParameters(true));
    }

    public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data)
    {
        return gne.Encrypt(data, false);
    }

    public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data)
    {
        byte[] d = eng.Decrypt(data, false);
        return d;
    }
```

Due to request I've included the keys - at the time I generated them with pepta.net:

```
    private readonly static string KKEY = @"
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBOQIBAAJBALrz8nKq+vpVBnZTNTM/jaRDRTdKPdS6c59+Fb4cEHF4Tj959EWH
dxpP0neCzXYeygJoVMjGshsOo59YoQXcGeUCAwEAAQJAMTauiAkCcIuZW+SjiI4e
VzNuMRPWGv3KGh4y0wzIN1YkvQvRgi9vTfY5AqGK1SRtlwcLuXJz2MyYUpcK5yJX
MQIhAOisz2NriiIHzBoklOVYKcx4fy8OdSUa70dFHWOs+jITAiEAzbHCoFBFXiIL
AZ2AUJojuNAtmktpCU1HK+42xA0+wycCIDmpAagAsXWnewQLhr6jL5CVV+dgbNVq
LFv8G8Fkz4fzAiBu8XXcKe+AOjRdhqnyz3B8+ivekNXyYnAEzdNUIyC6+QIgK4Rd
Y+ShRJK2nXZ5JUbz+FfwpzYYBVEaGg8dKK7nRcw=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

        private static readonly string xmlKKEY = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>uvPycqr6+lUGdlM1Mz+NpENFN0o91Lpzn34VvhwQcXhOP3n0RYd3Gk/Sd4LNdh7KAmhUyMayGw6jn1ihBdwZ5Q==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>6KzPY2uKIgfMGiSU5VgpzHh/Lw51JRrvR0UdY6z6MhM=</P><Q>zbHCoFBFXiILAZ2AUJojuNAtmktpCU1HK+42xA0+wyc=</Q><DP>OakBqACxdad7BAuGvqMvkJVX52Bs1WosW/wbwWTPh/M=</DP><DQ>bvF13CnvgDo0XYap8s9wfPor3pDV8mJwBM3TVCMguvk=</DQ><InverseQ>K4RdY+ShRJK2nXZ5JUbz+FfwpzYYBVEaGg8dKK7nRcw=</InverseQ><D>MTauiAkCcIuZW+SjiI4eVzNuMRPWGv3KGh4y0wzIN1YkvQvRgi9vTfY5AqGK1SRtlwcLuXJz2MyYUpcK5yJXMQ==</D></RSAKeyValue>";

        private readonly static string PKEY = @"
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBALrz8nKq+vpVBnZTNTM/jaRDRTdKPdS6
c59+Fb4cEHF4Tj959EWHdxpP0neCzXYeygJoVMjGshsOo59YoQXcGeUCAwEAAQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

        private static readonly string xmlPKEY = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>uvPycqr6+lUGdlM1Mz+NpENFN0o91Lpzn34VvhwQcXhOP3n0RYd3Gk/Sd4LNdh7KAmhUyMayGw6jn1ihBdwZ5Q==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tested this using my own keys and it works fine, so the issue is most likely related to your key XML. Can you add the keys as well as the code you're using to call the encrypt and decrypt methods?

Comment: Your keys also work for me. Is there possibly an issue with how you're displaying the results, or with the data you're trying to decrypt?

Comment: @Syon What I'm trying to decrypt is a 32-byte (256 bit, the purpose of the data is pretty explicit at this point) array, which gets encrypted successfully by the same code. The data is populated using Random.NextBytes() - might this be the culprit?

Comment: Random.NextBytes() would not cause an issue, the data being encrypted can be anything. I meant more, is it possible that the issue is not with the algorithm or keys, but the way you're calling and algorithm and display the results. A complete example (void Main and all) that reproduces the issue might be helpful.

Comment: The whole code is not necessary - what it does is just storing the decrypted data into a byte array in my class, like this:

byte[32] decrypted = Crypto.Decrypt(encrypted);